# Fix align-items "center" input/button mismatch

Tags: css

Why button shrinks in size when `align-items: center` and how to fix it?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-cherry-bjjsd?file=/src/App.tsx).

[image]

---

Code:

```
const MenuSvg = () => {
  return (
    <svg
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      strokeWidth="2"
      stroke="black"
      strokeLinecap="round"
      strokeLinejoin="round"
      className="svg"
    >
      <line x1="3" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"></line>
      <line x1="3" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6"></line>
      <line x1="3" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18"></line>
    </svg>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <button className="button">Hello</button>
        <button className="button">
          <MenuSvg />
        </button>
        <input className="input" />
      </div>
      <hr />
      align-items: "center":
      <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <button className="button">Hello</button>
        <button className="button">
          <MenuSvg />
        </button>
        <input className="input" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Styles:

```
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS. */
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 55px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Times";
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.svg {
  height: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.button {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.input {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in flex align-items default is stretch, all children will use all the available space. If you set it to center, children will only use the space that is needed, your button shrinks because if need less space than the input.
To fix this, you need to set the height for your element.

Comment: if i set height then padding stops working :(

Comment: It irrelevant, I checked your code sandbox, it seems working fine.

Comment: It's because i've changed to box-sizing: content-box

Answer (score 0):

**Because align-items align the field in center of whole screen, and it takes auto height and width for the div. Try to use custom height and width for that.**

**Or you can use alignSelf CSS property as below:**

[alignSelf Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHnTL.png)